# UIView shadow issue on real device - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow

I have a tableview cell with view inside and I want to add shadow to it.

For this reason I add this code:

```
self.PrimaView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.PrimaView.bounds).cgPath
self.PrimaView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
self.PrimaView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
self.PrimaView.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
```

This is tableview cell structure:

[image]

My problem is this:

when I execute code on simulator I get this (this is what I want to get):

[image]

but when I execute the same code on the real device I get this:

[image]

Why is it different than the previous image?

Comment: Because your view got resized. You have to update `shadowPath` from `UIView.layoutSubviews` (ideally only when the size actually changes).

Comment: Thank you!! One question: why on simulator I dont have this problem?

Comment: Probably it has a different screen size than your device.

Answer (score 0):

@Sulthan is right or may be you have safe area issue as well if you have same device if not.
Then you can use this code for shadow

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CardViewMaterial: UIView {

//    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.black
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to call `super.layoutSubviews`. You should check that the bounds have changed before changing `shadowPath`, otherwise you are killing performance.